# Running multiple CMD commands at once

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Wondering what I may be doing wrong, currently trying to revise this CMD to the [proper format](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) but it's not running right. The original w/ no edit is running good, but using the array version is not. Does combining commands not work in the proper format, or what may I be missing? Modified version when run immediately exits once it starts

Original:

```
CMD sshd & cd /app && npm start
```

Modified:

```
CMD ["sshd", "&", "cd", "/app", "&&", "npm", "start"]
```

My complete dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force

# CMD sshd & cd /app && npm start
# CMD ["sshd", "&", "cd", "/app", "&&", "npm", "start"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should:

1. Delete `sshd`: it's not installed in your image, it's unnecessary, and it's all but impossible to set up securely.
2. Delete the `cd` part, since the `WORKDIR` declaration above this has already switched into that directory.
3. Then your `CMD` is just a simple command.

```bash
FROM node:10-alpine
# note, no sshd, user accounts, host keys, ...
WORKDIR /app         # does the same thing as `cd /app`
COPY . /app
RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

If you want to run multiple commands or attempt to launch an unmanaged background process, all of these things require a shell to run and you can't usefully use the `CMD` exec form.  In the form you show in the question the main command is `sshd` only, and it takes 6 arguments including the literal strings `&` and `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

Define a script and put all of your commands into this script. 
Eg: I call this script is `startup.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
sshd
cd /app
npm start
```

And call this script in CMD

```
COPY startup.sh /app/data/startup.sh
CMD ["/app/data/startup.sh"]
```